# Objective-c - NSData initWithContentsOfFile vs. dataWithContentsOfFile

Tags: objective-c, nsdata

What is the difference between these two objective-c statements?

```
NSData *documentBytes = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
```

versus this:

```
NSData *documentBytes = [NSData initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
```

From Apple's NSData Class Reference page, it states the following about each

dataWithContentsOfFile -  Creates and returns a data object by reading every byte from the file specified by a given path.

initWithContentsOfFile -  Returns a data object initialized by reading into it the data from the file specified by a given path.

To me, these seem functionally equivalent but I highly doubt they do the same thing in all cases, right?

Thanks in advance...
-Ergin

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use `init`, you always have to use `alloc`, like so:

```
NSData *documentBytes = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
```

This returns an NSData object with a retain count of 1, you now own the reference and are responsible for releasing it.

When using `dataWithContentsOfFile`

```
NSData *documentBytes = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
```

You get back an autoreleased NSData object. You can use it and forget about it, the autorelease pool will take care of it. If you want to store it, you have to retain it.

Of course, when you are using ARC, you can forget about all of this ;-), the methods are essentially the same.

Answer (score 0):

The second

```
NSData *documentBytes = [NSData initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
```

Will not compile you will need to alloc it first, will look something like:

```
NSData *documentBytes = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
```

But one or another will work the same, in the end you will have an NSData that has the contet of the file. The first one is a shortcut.

So about your doubt:

The first one you do not need to alloc the object first, the method will return the object for you, if you are not using ARC (I do not think so), the first one will return an object that the system will take care.

The second one you will need to alloc the object first, the method only initialize your object, and if you are not using ARC you will need to take care to release it.

Comment: Ok that makes sense, and you're right the initWithContentsOfFile does not compile without the alloc.  Thanks, that's much clearer now!

Comment: I am glad to help you Ergin, so if it clarified your doubt, mark it as the accepted answer.